# MPI4PY: A Different Number of Nodes Returns A Different Result

Tags: python, mpi, rounding-error, mpi4py

I am relatively new to using MPI routines and I am confused as to why in the code below I will get different results depending on how many nodes I use.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

def MPI_sum(comm,x):
    xsum = np.sum(x)
    vals = comm.gather(xsum,root=0)

    if rank == 0:
        s = np.sum(vals)

    s = comm.bcast(s,root=0)

    return s

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()

datalen = 80000/size
x = np.zeros(datalen) + 1. + 1e-5

xsum = MPI_sum(comm,x)
if rank == 0:
    print xsum - np.floor(xsum)
```

I ran this code with 1 node and with 2 nodes. 
The answer I got from 1 node was:  0.800000153016
The answer I got from 2 nodes was: 0.800000035219

What is causing this discrepancy?

(As an added note, I did try passing all the x array data in MPI_sum to root=0 and then summing on root=0 and that gave me the correct answer; the same output regardless of the number of nodes. However passing all the data to one node is not practical for the code I will be implementing this in.)

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3):

The observed effect is caused by the non-associativity of the floating-point operations and is not specific to MPI applications, though the latter tend to expose it more often due to the partitioning of the problem domain. Observe the following to get an idea what happens:

```python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> datalen = 80000
>>> x = np.zeros(datalen) + 1. + 1e-5
>>> xsum = np.sum(x)
>>> xsum - np.floor(xsum)
0.80000015301629901
>>> xsum = np.sum(x[:datalen/2]) + np.sum(x[datalen/2:])
>>> xsum - np.floor(xsum)
0.80000003521854524
```

In other words, given a finite precision computer, summing the whole array is not the same as first summing the two halves of the array separately and then summing the two sums, no matter if you do this using MPI (as in your code) or serially (as in my example).

The reason for that is the last-bit rounding that takes place any time two floating-point numbers are added together. In time one learns to deal with those peculiarities of the floating-point arithmetic. There are special summation algorithms that prevent similar effects, e.g. the [Kahan summation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Note that 10<sup>-5</sup> is not exactly representable on any finite-precision binary computer since log<sub>2</sub>(10<sup>-5</sup>) = -5 x log<sub>2</sub>(10) and the binary logarithm of 10 is an irrational number.

Comment: I don't quite understand this though as I am using 64bit floats shouldn't the precision be to the order of 2^64 (10^19) significant figures, not 10^10?

Comment: There are 5 digits in the integer part and the fractional parts differ in the 7-th digit. That's 12 digits of precision. The rest are lost due to rounding errors while summing 80000 (~10^6) numbers. Compare against the result from the Kahan algorithm.